# Novel with gang conflict and cybernetics

Tags: story-identification, books, crime

This was a science fiction book from the 2010s. It might have been part of a series.

It had a Hispanic teenage girl lead, I believe. She might have refused to get cybernetic enhancements for some reason while the rest of the world had them. Her family that was on the poorer side was caught up in some gang conflict in the area of the city where she lived.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The novel was called [Bluescreen](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/20499652-bluescreen).

> djinni—a smart device implanted right in a person’s head.

> Marisa Carneseca is one of those people. She might spend her days in Mirador, the small, vibrant LA neighborhood

These details do match up with what I remember.